# Jquery validation fails on dynamically added rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using `jquery validation plugin` and it is not applied on dynically added rows
my `code` is:

**Html:**

```
<form action="test.php" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div id="add_rows"> 
        <div class="new-row">
            <input type="text" required="required" name="qty[]" /><br />
            <textarea required="required" name="test[]" rows='4' cols='15'></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button>Add</button>
</form>
```

**Script:**

```
var frm=$('form').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // do other stuff for a valid form
        alert('form submitted');
        return false;
    }
});

$('button').on('click',function(){
    $clone=$('.new-row:first').clone();
    $clone.find('input,textarea').val('');      
    $clone.insertAfter($('.new-row:last'));
    $clone.find('input,textarea').rules('add',{required:true});
    $('.new-row:last').find('input,textarea').rules('add',{required:true});
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YjgQ6/2/)

Another issue, I have tried it on my system and I got error like : `TypeError: e is null`
for the line `$clone.find('input,textarea').rules('add',{required:true});` if I remove then error not comes,
but this error is not seen in `fiddle`

Comment: jQuery Validate plugin requires that you **must** have unique `name` attributes on each input to be validated.  Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with the way you've implemented `rules('add')`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, i think this is what you wanted

Added unique name to the textarea and input.

```
var incr = 0;
$('button').on('click',function(){
    incr++;
    $clone=$('.new-row:first').clone();
    $clone.find('input,textarea').val('');
    $clone.find('input').attr('name','qty'+incr+'[]');
    $clone.find('textarea').attr('name','test'+incr+'[]');
```

[**Demo  here**](http://jsfiddle.net/YjgQ6/4/)

Comment: Your `code` gives `error` `TypeError: $.data(...) is undefined`, plz check in `console`, also here the validation not working. It is `HTML5 required` whick  makes the `border red`.

Comment: Ah, i see checking it out now

Comment: @RohanKumar You can check this one out, http://jsfiddle.net/YjgQ6/4/ what i did is added a unique name for each textarea and input

Comment: @Anton Not suited. This `data` is stored in `database` after `post`. So, at `server side` how can I get different post variables? Thats why I created array of elements like `qty[]`.

Comment: I'm not sure, might be possible to have qty[] in another attribute? `<input type="text" name="input1" required="required" data="qty[]"/>`